# Как скопировать данные из буфера обмена в значение input

Tags: javascript

По нажатию на кнопку должен быть вставлен текст из буфера обмена, но выходит ошибка `Cannot read property "clipboardData" of undefined`.

```js
const pasteFromBuffer = document.querySelector('.paste-button');
const textareaPaste = document.querySelector('.input');

function handlePaste(event) {
  const clipboardData = event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
  const pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');
  console.log(pastedData);
  textareaPaste.innerText = pastedData;
}

pasteFromBuffer.addEventListener('click', handlePaste);
```

```html
<input class="input"></input>
<button class="paste-button">Paste</button>
```

Comment: А что тут должно происходить?

Comment: по нажатию на кнопку в инпут должен быть вставлен текст из буфера обмена

Comment: Не понятен контекст, но, возможно, нужно дождаться загрузки DOM:  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { })

Comment: @Александр, нет, тут он точно успеет прогрузится.

Comment: @Imp3l, на `click` такого свойства нету. `clipboardData` - этого тоже. Если я правильно помню, есть оно на событиях буфера - `paste`,....

Comment: @Node_pro как тогда сделать, чтобы при клике на кнопку в инпут вставлялся текст из буфера обмена?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться [clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API), сделав вот так:

```
const pasteFromBuffer = document.querySelector( ".paste-button")
const textareaPaste = document.querySelector(".input")

const handlePaste = async event => {
    const clipboardData = await navigator.clipboard.readText()
    textareaPaste.value = clipboardData
    console.log(textareaPaste.value)
}

pasteFromBuffer.addEventListener("click", handlePaste, false)
```

Имейте ввиду что большинство браузеров запросят у пользователя подтверждения прав доступа к данным clipboard.

Так же этот метод не будет работать из консоли, так как требует непосредственного действия пользователя, например, нажатия на кнопку.